# storybook argTypes control type

Tags: reactjs, styled-components, storybook

my interface:

```
interface TextProps {
  w?: number | string;
  h?: number | string;
}
```

my Text Component Style:

```
  width: ${p => (typeof p.w === 'number' ? p.w + 'px' : p.w)};
  height: ${p => (typeof p.h === 'number' ? p.h + 'px' : p.h)};
```

I want to 2 type(=string | number )in storybook argTypes...

```
export default {
  title: 'Core/Text',
  component: TextComponent,
  argTypes: {
   w: {}, // ?
h: {}, // ?
    margin: { control: 'object', table: { type: { summary: 'array' } }, description: '텍스트 margin 간격' },
    padding: { control: 'object', table: { type: { summary: 'array' } }, description: '텍스트 padding 간격' }
  }
} as Meta;
```

help me :(

```
export default {
  title: 'Core/Text',
  component: TextComponent,
  argTypes: {
    w: { control: { type: ['string' | 'number'] }, table: { type: { summary: ['number', 'string'] } }, description: '텍스트 가로 사이즈' },
    h: { control: ['string' | 'number'], table: { type: { summary: ['number', 'string'] } }, description: '텍스트 높이 사이즈' },
    margin: { control: 'object', table: { type: { summary: 'array' } }, description: '텍스트 margin 간격' },
    padding: { control: 'object', table: { type: { summary: 'array' } }, description: '텍스트 padding 간격' }
  }
} as Meta;
```

[image]